# AMD latest driver "18.04" install on "19.04" min server

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

FWIW, I did look at a previous question supposedly answered, the "RX-460" one.

With RX-560 and 19.04 my system seems working fine but I need opencl so I tried that (latest) AMD driver at their site, the one that says 18.04.  The install failed "broken packages" but since all I needed was opencl then I read this
[here](http://linuxconfig.org/install-opencl-for-the-amdgpu-open-source-drivers-on-debian-and-ubuntu)

Tried installing the first item listed in the package, the "core" one, and got the following error that basically says the amd package 19.10 can only be installed on 18.04 !!!

```
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-core 19.10-785425 [2,416 B]
(Reading database ... 100259 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb ...
ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.
```

[EDIT] The 19.10 was driver version of AMD, not Ubuntu version, my bad.
I put in 18.04 and tried again but same problem.  The chatter from the install
./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy,pal is [here](http://stateson.net/images/18_opencl_prob.txt) In the mean time, I managed to install an SLIC2.1 on this really dual xeon system  so will try windows 7 pro

Answer (score 0):

I finally got that AMD driver to install correctly on 18.04 but I had to do a minimal desktop. I am guessing that the dependency errors during the install on the server were caused by the AMD driver expecting some type of desktop to work with.  This was only a BOINC mining system (gridcoin) that did not need a desktop.  Pic here [open rack frame](http://stateson.net/images/biostar_tb85.png)